# Using pyleus: NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichBolt

Tags: python, apache-storm, pyleus

Seems like a `NoClassDefFoundError` would be an easy thing to fix, however I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm using pyleus on the [word_count example](https://github.com/Yelp/pyleus/tree/develop/examples/word_count). I am able to build using:

```
pyleaus build word_count/pyleus_topology.yaml
```

Then I attempt to run local (or even if I attempt to submit, I get the same error):

```
pyleus local --debug word_count.jar

Running: /mypath/jre/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/mypath/storm -Dstorm.log.dir=/mypath/storm/logs -Djava.library.path=/mypath/jre/lib/ -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /mypath/storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/mypath/storm/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:word_count.jar:/mypath/storm/conf:/mypath/storm/bin -Dstorm.jar=word_count.jar com.yelp.pyleus.PyleusTopologyBuilder --local --debug
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichBolt
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

What's confusing to me here is that it does look like all the storm libs are included in the classpath if you scroll on my error log. What am I missing here? I'm using Storm 1.0.1, pyleus 0.3.0, Java 1.8, Python 2.7.

Comment: Does anyone know if pyleus works for Storm 1.0.1?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Marking this as a dup of a very generic explanation of what NoClassDefFoundError is is quite frankly an overreach on your part. None of the answers fit well to quickly answer the question as to why my issue is there without a lot of digging. I am sure others will run into this because it is not obvious that pyleus does not support the newer versions of Storm.

Comment: same reason for every instance of that error and the same answer for every question about this error, put the missing class on the classpath, *how you do that for your particular situation is extremely localized*, what version of whatever is irrelevant, does not change the reason this exception happens or how to fix it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson My mistake for marking this java when this isn't really a java programming question (even though it is a java error). I see no reason that python developers should have to learn the ins and outs of Java and track down this issue, and I'm sure others will bump into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question.  Based on what I'm seeing in github.com and the javadocs... I believe pyleus does not support 1.0.1.  The javadocs show that in previous revisions, IRichBolt was in `backtype.storm.topology` however now it exists in `org.apache.storm.topology`.  Who knows what else is incompatible.

So I guess for now, run an older version of Storm (I only saw a reference to 0.9.4 being compatible, so perhaps 0.9.6 would also work).  I did see that there is an open pull request for 0.10.0 being worked on, so I guess it might be awhile before 1.0.1 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You are right and I got the similar issue, reported at [IRichBolt Error when running topology on storm-1.0.0 and pyleus-0.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242655/irichbolt-error-when-running-topology-on-storm-1-0-0-and-pyleus-0-3-0)
I tried to fix it as follows: got the pyleus source code from GitHub, imported all files including pom file from com\yelp\pyleus into Eclipse, in java files changed backtype.storm.topology to org.apache.storm.topology, compiled new *.class files, unzipped pyleus_base.jar, replaced old *.class files with the newly compiled in Eclipse, zipped back to pyleus_base.jar, placed it in the pyleus module, submitted storm topology and got another error,related to kafka's portion of pyleus module. I found another set kafka's *.class files in the pyleus_base.jar which need to be fixed too and it seems too much need to be done to resolve the issue. I Still did not fix it yet.

Comment: It looks like the latest (bleeding edge) version of streamparse may work as an alternative, although I haven't tried yet.  `pip install --pre streamparse==3.0.0.dev3`

Comment: Thought I would follow up that I was able to get streamparse with storm 1.0.1 working (although I did have to apply a couple diffs from github that aren't in 3.0.0.dev3 yet).