# IRichBolt Error when running topology on storm-1.0.0 and pyleus-0.3.0

Tags: python, apache-storm, topology, pyleus

I'm running storm topology "`pyleus --verbose local xyz_topology.jar`" using `storm-1.0.0, pyleus-0.3.0, centos-6.6` and getting the Error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   backtype/storm/topology/IRichBolt

```
Running: java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0
-Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/    
lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar    
:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/storm-core-1.0.0.jar:
/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.0.jar:xyzTopology.jar:
/usr/local/storm/conf:/usr/local/apache-storm-1.0.0/bin
-Dstorm.jar=xyz_topology.jar com.yelp.pyleus.PyleusTopologyBuilder --local
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichBolt
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
pyleus local: error: [StormError] Storm command failed. Run with --verbose for more info.
```

The same topology worked well and without any errors when using the old version of `storm-0.10.0 and pyleus-0.3.0`.

I looked at the storm-0.10.0 and storm-1.0.0 docs and found that in storm-1.0.0

(a) the package structure has been changed and

(b) the IRichBolt class is not presented and instead of that there are two new classes - BaseStatefulBoltExecutor and BasicBoltExecutor - which implement IRichBolt interface.

It seems new `storm-1.0.0` release can't work with `pyleus-0.3.0` as it was with old `storm-0.10.0` version.

*What would be the best solution to resolve the issue and allow to run the topology on `storm-1.0.0` and `pyleus-0.3.0`* ?

Comment: I tried to fix it as follows: got the pyleus source code from GitHub, imported all files including pom file from com\yelp\pyleus into Eclipse, in java files changed backtype.storm.topology to org.apache.storm.topology, compiled new *.class files, unzipped pyleus_base.jar, replaced old *.class files with the newly compiled in Eclipse, zipped back to pyleus_base.jar, placed it in the pyleus module, submitted storm topology and got another error, related to kafka's portion of pyleus module.

Answer (score 1):

Storm 1.0.0 includes a major refactoring with regard to package names. All packages `backtype/*` got replaced by `org/apache/storm`. Thus, you need to recompile your topology using Storm 1.0.0 (including some code change; ie, using different `import`s to align to the new package structure).

As an alternative, you can enable backward compatibility in your Storm cluster (see https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/index.html)

> ```
> NOTE
> ```
>
> In the latest version, the class packages have been changed from "backtype.storm" to "org.apache.storm" so the topology code compiled with older version won't run on the Storm 1.0.0 just like that. Backward compatibility is available through following configuration
>
> client.jartransformer.class: "org.apache.storm.hack.StormShadeTransformer"
>
> You need to add the above config in storm installation if you want to run the code compiled with older versions of storm. The config should be added in the machine you use to submit your topologies.
>
> Refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1202 for more details.

Comment: Thank you Matthias for the response. I looked at the provided links (https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/index.html and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1202) but still unclear.  Could you please explain what does this mean "add the above config in storm installation", what exactly need to be done to resolve the issue ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the configuration to conf/storm.yaml file.