# Intellij IDEA maven : can't resolve symbol "backtype"

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea, apache-storm

I'm writing a Wordcount on storm with input from kafka. While I'm doing project on IDEA, I found maven failed to download every class I needed(actually most of the classes). 
the pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>stormkafka_wordcount</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormkafka_wordcount</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.building.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.building.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <kafka.version>0.10.1.0</kafka.version>
        <storm.version>1.0.2</storm.version>
        <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.3</hadoop.version>
        <hbase.version>1.2.3</hbase.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>${storm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Everything should be downloaded successfully with no error in this pom.xml. While in my java.class, it still say `backtype` not found, `storm` not found.

```
import storm.kafka.StringScheme;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
```

I do not use Virtual Machine and everything is installed directly in my OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.
I have ran Hadoop before using IDEA. Everything is fine. So the maven should be installed properly I thought.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IRichBolt Error when running topology on storm-1.0.0 and pyleus-0.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242655/irichbolt-error-when-running-topology-on-storm-1-0-0-and-pyleus-0-3-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After storm 1.0, `backtype.storm` changed to `org.apache.storm`.
Try to replace all the `backtype.storm` to `org.apache.storm`.
like

```
import storm.kafka.StringScheme;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
```

Comment: How to find these pieces info? I searched for this error for a long time and saw no relevant info. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, storm.kafka is not available either, I've tested it. Also need to change it to `org.apache.storm.kafka.StringScheme`